# Корень слова

Tags: морфология

В приведённых словах обозначила корени и указала, к какой группе по значению они относятся: 1-предметное,2-процессуальное,3-признаковое, 4 -количественное:

**Автомат**изировать (3), **чит**атель (2), **рыб**ачить (2), **син**ева (3), **тр**ойка (4), в**руч**ную (3), **масл**яный (3), **тверд**еть (2), **автомат**изированный (1), **ход**ок (2), **пят**ерня (4), у**добр**ить (1), **лёт**чик (2), **десят**ка (4), **дел**о(1), за**сахар**ить (1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значение корня совпадает с **частеречной характеристикой непроизводного слова**.

Автомат/изировать (1), чит/а/тель (2), рыб/ачить (1), син/ева (3), тр/ойка (4), в/руч/ную (1), масл/яный (1), тверд/еть (3), автомат/изированный (1), ход/ок (2), пят/ерня (4), у/добр/ить (3), лёт/чик (2), десят/ка (4), дел/о(1), за/сахар/ить (1)